# ReactJS - Passing a component as a return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im using React, useState and React-Icons.

My intention is to create a dropdown menu (without Bootstrap). I want to change the icon when clicked (to init the function) but the output is the raw SVG details. Any ideas?

```
import { IoMdArrowDropdownCircle, IoMdArrowDropupCircle } from "react-icons/io";
function navBar() {
    
  const navToggle = () => {
    const [navMenuToggle, changeNavToggle] = useState(true);
       return navMenuToggle ? (
         <IoMdArrowDropdownCircle />
       ) : (
         <IoMdArrowDropupCircle />
       );
    changeNavToggle(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="tableIcon" id="navDropdown" onClick={navToggle}>
        <IoMdArrowDropdownCircle />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default navBar;
```

Comment: I have a feeling i need to use some backticks?

Comment: `changeNavToggle(false)` is after return, meaning it will never be executed

Comment: Sorry i didn't include the extended code to keep it clean. I have edited the original post to include everything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use react hooks inside a function , they should always be in the react component before the return .

I'd suggest the easiest way to render a component conditionally like this :

```
export default function RenderComponent() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  
  return show ? <ComponentOne /> : <ComponentTwo />;
}
```

Or this way :

```
export default function RenderComponent() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  const render = () => {
   return show ? <ComponentOne /> : <ComponentTwo />
  }
  
  return render() ;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't include the extended code to keep it clean. I have edited the original post to include everything relevant.

Comment: You can use hooks inside a function if you are creating a hook

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by making a clickhandler function to change the state and a function to return the icon.

```
  <div className="tableIcon" id="navDropdown" onClick={navToggle}>
     {createIcon()}
  </div>
```

functions

```
  const [navMenuToggle, changeNavToggle] = useState("true");
  const navToggle = () => {
    if (navMenuToggle == "true") {
      changeNavToggle("false");
      document.getElementById("menuDD").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      changeNavToggle("true");
      document.getElementById("menuDD").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  };

  const createIcon = () => {
    if (navMenuToggle == "true") {
      return <IoMdArrowDropdownCircle />;
    } else {
      return <IoMdArrowDropupCircle />;
    }
  };
```